# dynamic group form in flutter

Tags: flutter, forms, dart

I'm creating a dynamic form in which the user can add multiple fields. but the datas that I'm getting is incorrect. handling the textfield is not a problem but the hard part is handling dropdown. first let me add the code.

first i created a controller class

```
class _GroupControllers {
  TextEditingController phone = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();
  DropModel selectedCatagory = DropModel();
  void dispose() {
    phone.dispose();
    email.dispose();
    selectedCatagory;
  }
}
```

and initialize them

```
List<TextFormField> _phoneFields = [];
  List<TextFormField> _emailFields = [];
  List<_GroupControllers> _groupControllers = [];
  List<DropdownButtonFormField2> _categoryDropDown = [];
```

and created a tile to add the group forms upon user press

```
Widget _addTile(int index) {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text("Add Phone"),
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final group = _GroupControllers();

                final phoneField = _generateTextField(group.phone,
                    "phone number", RegExp(r'(^(?:[+0]9)?[0-9]{10,12}$)'));

                final emailField = _generateTextField(
                    group.email,
                    "email",
                    RegExp(
                        r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+"));
                final categoryDropdown =
                    _generatedDropDown(category, _groupControllers.length);
                print("from tile adder ${_groupControllers.length + 1}");

                index == 0
                    ? setState(() {
                        _groupControllers.add(group);
                        _phoneFields.add(phoneField);
                        _emailFields.add(emailField);
                        _categoryDropDown.add(categoryDropdown);
                        phones.add(Phones());
                      })
                    : setState(() {
                        _groupControllers.removeAt(index);
                        _phoneFields.removeAt(index);
                        _emailFields.removeAt(index);
                        _categoryDropDown.removeAt(index);
                      });
              },
              icon: index == 0
                  ? const Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    )
                  : const Icon(
                      CupertinoIcons.minus,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

and for the textfields

```
TextFormField _generateTextField(
      TextEditingController controller, String hint, RegExp pattern) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please enter ${hint}';
        } else if (!pattern.hasMatch(value)) {
          return 'Enter a valid ${hint}';
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: hint),
    );
  }
```

and for the dropdown

```
DropdownButtonFormField2 _generatedDropDown(
      List<String> category, int index) {
    final group = _GroupControllers();
    print("...................$index");
    return DropdownButtonFormField2(
      //key: _key,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        isDense: true,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
      ),
      isExpanded: true,
      hint: const Text(
        'Select Category',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
      ),
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.arrow_drop_down,
        color: Colors.black45,
      ),
      iconSize: 30,
      buttonHeight: 60,
      buttonPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
      items: category
          .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: item,
                child: Text(
                  item,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                  ),
                ),
              ))
          .toList(),
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null) {
          return 'Please select Catagory.';
        }
      },
      onChanged: (value) {
        //Do something when changing the item if you want.
        setState(() {
          selDrop.selected!.removeAt(index);
          selDrop.selected!.insert(index, value);
        });
      },
      onSaved: (value) {
        selDrop.selected!.indexOf(index.toString());
        selDrop.selected!.removeAt(index);
        selDrop.selected!.insert(index, value);
      },
    );
  }
```

and my `ListView.builder`

```
ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  //scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount: _groupControllers.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: height * 0.005),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: width * 0.02,
                              vertical: height * 0.01),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              _addTile(index),
                              Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    "Phone Number:",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: width * 0.04,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        letterSpacing: width * 0.002),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: height * 0.005,
                                  ),
                                  _phoneFields[index],
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: height * 0.005,
                              ),
                              Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    "Email:",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: width * 0.04,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        letterSpacing: width * 0.002),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: height * 0.005,
                                  ),
                                  _emailFields[index],
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: height * 0.005,
                              ),
                              Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    "Category:",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: width * 0.04,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        letterSpacing: width * 0.002),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: height * 0.005,
                                  ),
                                  _categoryDropDown[index]
                                  // _generatedDropDown(
                                  //     category, index, ObjectKey(index))
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: height * 0.005,
                              ),
                            ],
                          )),
                    );
                  }),
```

so the error I'm facing is when i fetch the datas of the text field it is good. but the dropdown not working. i even used the dropdown separately by not including into the `GroupController`. what i did is.

first i created a model

```
class DropModel {
  List<String>? selected;
  String? sel;

  DropModel({this.selected, this.sel});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();

    data['selected'] = selected;

    return data;
  }
}
```

then used it in my page like `DropModel selDrop = DropModel();`. and as you have seen above in the dropdown form in the `onChanged` and `onSaved`

```
onChanged: (value) {
        //Do something when changing the item if you want.
        setState(() {
          selDrop.selected!.removeAt(index);
          selDrop.selected!.insert(index, value);
        });
      },
      onSaved: (value) {
        selDrop.selected!.indexOf(index.toString());
        selDrop.selected!.removeAt(index);
        selDrop.selected!.insert(index, value);
      },
```

and i printed the value as follows

let's say i added 3 group forms

```
//i removed the first val b/c it returns empty string ""
selDrop.selected!.removeWhere((element) => element == "");
print(json.encode(selDrop.selected));
```

the result is `["Manager","Sales","Service"]`. these are correct. but then i wanted to change the second value the result will be `["Manager","Reception","Sales","Service"]`. these are not correct it should be `["Manager","Reception","Service"]`. and now if i add one more group form and assign value the result will be `["Manager","Reception","Sales","Sales","Service"]` but it should be `["Manager","Reception","Service","Sales"], why is this happening? sorry that the question is long

Answer (score 0):

Use "Map<String, String>" instead,

initialize at page start

```
Map<String, String> data  = {};
```

When Function is called assign the values as follows:

```
DropdownButtonFormField2 _generatedDropDown(
      List<String> category, int index) {
   data.putIfAbsent('$index', () => '');
   onChanged : (String? val) {
    if(data.containsKey('$index') && val !=null) {
    data['$index'] = val!;
   }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Preferably don't use "setState" when working with forms, use other state management solutions. if you must, then extract the widget that requires "setState" into a stateful widget and then internally manage the state there

Comment: does that mean i don't need the model

Comment: it works but now when i remove an item it it adds an empty string `{"0":"Service","1":"Reception","2":"Service","3":"Sales","4":""}`

Comment: remove the key and value from the map while removing the item.

Comment: using `if (data.containsKey('$index')) {
                          data.remove(index);
                        }`? or by `data.removeWhere((index, value) => false);`